# Julia function returning anonymous function

Tags: julia

I am trying to understand a relatively simple piece of code, but I am not quite able to reason what is happening (I am a Julia newbie coming from Python/Matlab background).

```
function myfunc(number::Integer)
    double() = 2*number
    square() = number^2
    return _ -> (number, double, square)
end
```

I understand `myfunc` is returning an anonymous function that does not care for the value passed to it. So these cases make sense to me:

```
julia> n4 = myfunc(4)
#9 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> n4(50)
(4, var"#double#10"{Int64}(4), var"#square#11"{Int64}(4))
```

In the first line `n4` refers to the *anonymous* function itself, whereas in the second the anonymous function is called with parameter `50` and does what it is supposed to: discards 50 and returns the tuple containing data it was *defined* with.

What I don't understand is how I am able to do:

```
julia> n4.square
(::var"#square#11"{Int64}) (generic function with 1 method)

julia> n4.square()
16
```

The fact that `n4` which refers to an anonymous function has *child* objects `n4.number`, `n4.double`, `n4.square` is a surprise to me. How is `n4` behaving as if it were a struct? Doing `n4(*)[2]()` to get back 8 as answer makes sense but when `fieldnames(n4)` fails something is happening behind the scenes that I don't understand to make `n4.double()` work. Where/what is the mechanism by which I am able to use `.` after `n4` to get at the functions/data?

Comment: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/#Function-like-objects-1

Comment: Have a look at `Meta.@lower function myfunc()...`. That will tell you pretty much anything about the details, if you get used to reading lowered code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Julia, all generic functions (that is, all regular Julia-defined functions) are structs. Any struct can be made callable in Julia, so by default, a normal function is just a zero-field struct (a singleton) made callable. In other words, doing

`foo(x) = x+1`

is similar to

```
struct Foo end
const foo = Foo()
(::Foo)(x) = x + 1
```

This works great for normal functions, but for anonymous functions, this can cause the creation of a large number of new types. For example, you could do:
`functions = [x -> x+i for i in 1:1000]`.

Instead of creating 1000 new types, each with a new value of `i`, Julia here creates a single type containing `i` as a field, and 1000 instances.

In your case, instead of `myfunc` returning a new type for every invokation and returning the singleton instance of that type, it returns an instance of a type with the fields `number`, `double` and `square`.

Also, you can totally call fieldnames, you just have to call it on a type: `fieldnames(typeof(myfunc(4)))`.

It's just an optimization, and it feels a little strange that you have code relying on the internals of how functions are represented in memory. You probably shouldn't do that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jakob. It will probably take some time for me to fully understand. In the meantime, can I ask a follow-up question? If all functions are structs, can I expose local variables? Say I had `function test(x) var = x+4; z = var * var end` would it be possible to access `var` somehow? I thought we shouldn't be able to, and if possible, it is probably not recommended - but I am just asking for my edification.

Comment: Just return it as an additional argument: `test(x) = let var = x+4, z = var*var; var, z; end`.

Comment: No, that is not possible. It *can't* be possible, because the compilation process is free to remove variables. E.g. if you do `f(x) = (a = 1; 2)`, `a` cannot be accessed, because it's never instantiated.

Comment: @phipsgabler I meant in the style/format of `test.var` or `somebasefunc(test).var` but I conclude from Jakob's reply that it is not possible.

Comment: Ah, but you can define a callable struct for that. Ask a new question about that, comments are too small for writing something readable about it.